# Facebook Error: Failed to create your 3D Photo: Try again or learn more about how to create 3D Photos

Tags: photos, facebook, 3d

I created a stereoscopic 3D photo from scratch using [mirrors](http://poppy3d.com/) & [depth map generation](https://superuser.com/questions/1392438/how-do-i-convert-stereoscopic-3d-photos-sjpg-side-by-side-interlaced-to-fac/1428534#1428534) on an old camera.

I've tried various ways to upload it to Facebook. However, I always get errors.

How can I upload a grayscale depth map + RGB JPG to Facebook and get it to be in 3D?

[image]

This pair fails inexplicably:

[image]

NONE of these work:

Blurred from GIMP:

[image]

More RAW from Stereo Photo Maker:

[image]

Pixelized & Posterized from GIMP:

[image]

*GIMP* → *Enhance* → *Symmetric Nearest Neighbor* doesn't seem to help either, oddly:

[image]

And even hand sanitizing that still fails:

[image]

Even with a heavy median blur to join like-regions together, no luck:

[image]

I noticed there was a canvas size issue in GIMP, so I resized the photo but it still didn't work:

[image]

---

However, this works fine (use the grayscale as the RGB layer for testing):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It definitely is the aspect ratio.** I made all variants with same result (error) on a vertical image and then changed the size to a "square-ish" shape (750x918px) and it worked.

Comment: I think it has to be 4:3. Facebook has habit or releasing undocumented features. Very poor habit for one of the tech leaders.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an illustration wich I would like to share using 3D effects. So, I discovered that **3D images on Facebook must have aspect ratio 2:3 or below**, or conversion will fail. I changed my images aspect ratio **(no other changes)** and it worked perfectly! Try to do that too!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the *only* way I could get it to work is via injecting metadata into the image via [Omnivirt](https://www.omnivirt.com/3d-photo/).  (And despite what they claim, you CAN upload via the website using the *_depth.jpg trick, but only after injecting the metadata into the RGB image.) I have theories that there may be a 4:3 aspect ratio or pixel limitation as well, but I haven't done more extensive testing.